correct preposition: [in a light] or [under a light]
I have made up the sentences below.
(1a) I always find it easier to read small print in a light.
(1b) I always find it easier to read small print under a light.
Which preposition is correct? Thanks.

Under is better. Your in version almost suggests that the speaker/reader is inside a light fixture.

You can talk about doing something "in the light", meaning in a region that has good lighting (either from the sun or other light sources).

'I always find it easier to read small print in a strong light' is OK.

in good light or with good lighting

As @StuartF is stating, "light" can be used in different ways, e.g., a lighted region ("in the light"), or meaning a lamp ("under a light"). Of course, not to make light of this, there are yet other meanings for that word.

What @MichaelHarvey said. You can't read anything without light. I always find it easier to read small print in good light (without an article) is perfectly natural.
